# Node.js Socket pipe last packet

Tags: node.js

I have Node server ,This server creates a tcp socket connection with other side TCP server. I'm trying to pipe tcp data but when i was received a message for second time i got both the new message and the previous one(the first one) in the same stream. How can i fix this?

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1'; // parameterize the IP of the Listen 
var PORT = 6969; // TCP LISTEN port 
net.createServer(function(sock) {

    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        sock.write(data);
        socket.pipe(socket);
    });
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ' ' + sock.remotePort);
    });
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to create an echo server.

So you have two options - either piping:

```
// [...]
net.createServer(function(sock) {
   sock.pipe(sock);
}
// [...]
```

Or you subscribe data and manually write to the socket (which is the same as pipe)

```
// [...]
net.createServer(function(sock) {
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        sock.write(data);
    });
}
// [...]
```

With your current program, when someone sends data the first time you echo the data but also create a pipe connection which means next time the data is sent twice (as you described).